# Downgrading m2e to 1.5 version in Eclipse Mars

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a problem. I need to use Maven 2.x in Eclipse Mars. It has m2e 1.6 which doesn't support Maven 2.x.  I have to downgrade m2e to 1.5 version.... but I have no idea how... It's not possible to uninstall it in Eclipse, I removed all files from plugin folder containing m2e files, but still... Eclipse doesn't let me to install m2e 1.5 because it says the newer version is already installed.... Is there any chance to do that?

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/a/31272175/2110620. I hope it helps.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compile maven projects with JDK 1.6 in Eclipse Mars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31163198/compile-maven-projects-with-jdk-1-6-in-eclipse-mars)